# How to populate data in text boxes on selection of an item using AJAX ,PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, fetch

I have a form where i need to get data in a text box when user selects a place. If the user chooses a place then the following name and amount will come in the following textbox. I have done the following but it is not working. Can anyone please help me with this?

**I have tried the following:**

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label for="" class="">Place</label>
    <select  name="place" id="place"  onchange="myplace();">
        <option value="">--Option from db--</option>
    </select>       
</div>

<div>
    <label for="" class="">Name</label>
    <input type="text"  name="myname" id="myname" value="<?php //if there is data in databas then it is shown here...otherwise the value will change according to the above selection?>" >  
</div>

<div>
    <label for="" class="">Amount</label>
    <input type="text"  name="myamnt" id="myamnt" value="<?php //if there is data in databas then it is shown here...otherwise the value will change according to the above selection?>" >  
</div>
```

**MySQL**:

```
if(!empty($_POST["myinitplace"]))
{
        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM all_data , my_place  WHERE all_data.place=my_place.place and all_data.place = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["myinitplace"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 
while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())   
{   
 $data['name']=$rows['name'] ;
 $data['myacc']=$rows['amount'] ;
                
}
echo json_encode($data);
                        
    }
```

**Ajax**

```
function myplace() 
{
        
    var a = document.getElementById("place").value;
    //alert(a);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            myinitplace : a 
        },
        dataType :  "JSON",
        success : function(data){
         document.getElementById("myname").value = data.name;
         document.getElementById("myamnt").value = data.myacc;
        }
    })  
}
```

Comment: What is your error? Is your AJAX posting to the correct URL? You haven't specified a URL so it will post back to the original URL that created the HTML being displayed. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, your SELECT statement is using old syntax. Use explicit JOIN syntax, either `"SELECT * FROM all_data INNER JOIN my_place WHERE ll_data.place=my_place.place and all_data.place = ?"` or `"SELECT * FROM all_data INNER JOIN my_place ON all_data.place=my_place.place and all_data.place = ?"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you have populated the select block with valid data in the following line:

```
 <option value="">--Option from db--</option>
```

such as

```
<option value="Place1">Place1</option>
<option value="Place2">Place2</option>
```

In that case, you need to slightly amend your HTML code so that it explicitly calls the PHP script (by specifying the url), so add the line in the ajax block:

```
 url: "xxxx.php",
```

Assuming that the PHP script's name is `testSO3Sept2023.php`, then the HTML will be:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
    <label for="" class="">Place</label>
    <select  name="place" id="place"  onchange="javascript:myplace();">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="Place1">Place1</option>
        <option value="Place2">Place2</option>

    </select>       
</div>

<div>
    <label for="" class="">Name</label>
    <input type="text"  name="myname" id="myname" value="" >  
</div>

<div>
    <label for="" class="">Amount</label>
    <input type="text"  name="myamnt" id="myamnt" value="" >  
</div>

<script>
function myplace() 
{
        
    var a = document.getElementById("place").value;
    //alert(a);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            myinitplace : a 
        },
        url: "testSO3Sept2023.php",
        dataType :  "JSON",
        success : function(data){
         document.getElementById("myname").value = data.name;
         document.getElementById("myamnt").value = data.myacc;
        }
    })  
}

</script>
```

PHP script (testSO3Sept2023.php) (this is a simple PHP just to demonstrate the passing of data thru AJAX, in real life please connect with a db)

```
<?php
if($_POST["myinitplace"]=="Place1"){
 $data['name']="New York" ;
 $data['myacc']="100.1" ;
                }

if($_POST["myinitplace"]=="Place2"){
 $data['name']="Beijing" ;
 $data['myacc']="20.2" ;
                }

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

You may view the result by this [sandbox](https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO3Sept2023.html)

Comment: can you please share the code in testSO3Sept2023.php script?

Comment: Sure, please see the above slightly revised answer including the PHP script.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.. But when I am trying to connect with database nothing comes up. Even there is no error. When I am doing with your code its running. Nothing is coming in the text box when I am trying to show field data from database.